# react-native-paho-mqtt ( Client.js Message.js) Failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, mqtt, paho

I use react-native-paho-mqtt in my project,but it failed to compile.

[image]

the package.json is showing bellow:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Instead add the relevant parts as text to your question.